# Eclipse 4.2 ADT Plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, adt

I'm trying to install the ADT Plugin for Eclipse and I get the following error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Android Native Development Tools 20.0.2.v201207191942-407447 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk.feature.group 20.0.2.v201207191942-407447)
  Missing requirement: Android Native Development Tools 20.0.2.v201207191942-407447 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk.feature.group 20.0.2.v201207191942-407447) requires 'org.eclipse.cdt.feature.group 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

I have tried reinstalling Eclipse. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Managed to resolve this with help from this link

https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq?hl=es#wstinstallerror

> 1. Select Help > Install New Software...
> 2. Click the link for Available Software Sites.
> 3. Ensure there is an update site named Helios. If this is not present, click Add... and enter http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios for the Location.

Now follow the usual steps to install the ADT plugin, it should be able to automatically get the missing classes needed from the update site added above.

If you are using the most recent version of Eclipse (Juno), the update site is http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno (so just change Helios to Juno)

Also if you see a checkbox named 'Include Update Sites', make sure it is ticked.

Answer (score 1):

Download [this](http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-20.0.2.zip) .zip file to your pc. From Install New Software, click Add then Archive and locate this .zip file on file system. Click OK and check if it is going to work.

Edit:

I guess this is a random bug with eclipe 4.2. It sometimes worked for me and other times not as to you. I suggest you use [Eclipse 3.7.2](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-372/indigosr2) and try it again and again until it succeeds.

Comment: I'm getting same problem as kel, this doesn't solve it for me :(

Answer (score 1):

There's a checkbox called "Contact all sites". It's the last checkbox under the plugin list.  This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. I ran eclipse as root and problem was solved. By the way, I'm using Linux Mint

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Eclipse 4.2 (Juno).

What solved it for me was running Eclipse as Administrator - right-click on Eclipse.exe, choose Run as Administrator. When ran like this, it had no issues with determining the needed dependencies and downloading them before installing ADT.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the "repository not found", I used http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ instead of https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ for the available software sites.

Answer (score 0):

Run Eclipse as administrator and follow the same steps as before! Worked a charm for me!

Answer (score 0):

I had success installing NDK on Juno by installing the CDT (C++ Developers Tool) for Juno... works like charmed, maybe this is the reason why the NDK installation failed in the first place since CDT is not pre-installed with Juno.. but Helios is...

CDT Download page -> http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php